# Python - Programacion Orientada a Objetos

Tags: python, poo

Aprendí hace poco POO y tengo este código que no me compila. No se que parte del código esta mal. EL código sin implementar la POO anda, pero cuando lo quise modificar me empezó a no andar el código.

Para mi hay algún problema en los self, o en las funciones.

```
import os
import speech_recognition as sr 
import subprocess as sub
#import pyautogui as auto para un futuro
import pyttsx3 as voz
import webbrowser

class Asistente:
    def __init__(self):

        self.engine = voz.init()
        self.voices = self.engine.getProperty('voices')
        #indice para voz [0]  - Ingles-ZIRA - [1] Español - [2] Español
        self.engine.setProperty('voice', self.voices[2].id)
        self.engine.setProperty("rate", 140)
        # Escuchar el audio con el micrófono de mi computadora
        self.engine.say(' Jueves no te puede entender ')

    def Interpretar(self):
        self.comando_de_audio = self.comando_de_audio.split(' ')
        youtube = ('YouTube' or 'youtube') in self.comando_de_audio
        escribir = ('bloc de notas') in self.comando_de_audio
        shutdown = ('apagar equipo') in self.comando_de_audio
        telegram = ('Telegram' or 'telegram') in self.comando_de_audio 
        spotify = ('Spotify') in self.comando_de_audio
        clima = ('Clima') in self.comando_de_audio
        #vereda = ('Playlist Vereda') in comando_de_audio
        #RAM = ('ram' or 'Ram')  in comando_de_audio
        #estatus =  
  
        def apagarequipo(self):    
            self.sub.call('start shutdown /s', shell = True )
        def abrirblocNotas(self):
            self.sub.call('start notepad.exe', shell = True) 
            self.engine.say(' Abriendo Block de Notas ')
            self.engine.runAndWait()
        def abriryoutube(self):
            self.engine.say(' Abriendo Youtube ')
            self.engine.runAndWait()
            self.webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/")
            #sub.call(r'C:/Users/Jeremias Davison/Desktop/Assistant Charlotte/Batch/youtube.bat')
        def abrirtelegram(self):
            self.engine.say(' Abriendo Telegram ')
            self.engine.runAndWait()
            sub.call(r'C:/Users/Jeremias Davison/AppData/Roaming/Telegram Desktop/Telegram.exe')
        def abrirSpotify(self):
            self.engine.say('Abriendo Spotify')
            self.engine.runAndWait()
            self.sub.call(r'C:/Users/Jeremias Davison/AppData/Roaming/Spotify/Spotify.exe')

        if youtube:
            abriryoutube()
        elif escribir:
            abrirblocNotas()   
        elif telegram:
            abrirtelegram()
        elif spotify:
            abrirSpotify()
        elif shutdown:
            apagarequipo()
    
    def Run(self, Interpretar):
        self.r = self.sr.Recognizer()
        with self.sr.Microphone() as self.mic:
            self.engine.say(' Jueves te escucha ')
            self.engine.runAndWait()
            self.audio = self.r.listen(self.mic, 4)#3 segundo y se apaga el microfono
        try:
            self.comando = self.r.recognize_google(self.audio, language = 'es-AR')
            print(self.comando)
            Interpretar(self.comando) # lo que se debe hacer con el comando de audio
        except self.sr.UnknownValueError:
            self.engine.say(' Jueves no te puede entender ')
        except self.sr.RequestError as e:
            # si no se tiene conexión a internet o al servicio de google
            self.engine.say(' No pude obtener respuesta del servicio de Google Recognition ')
            print(" No pude obtener respuesta del servicio de Google Recognition ; {0} ". format(e))

if __name__ == "__main___":
    Jueves = Asistente()
    Jueves.Run()
```

Lo siguiente es lo que me muestra en la consola, compila pero no ejecuta el código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pusiste un "_" de más en la linea `if __name__ == "__main___"` luego de la palabra main. No se ejecuta por que el condicional antes mencionado te da False

Comment: Además en esta linea `('YouTube' or 'youtube') in self.comando_de_audio` supongo que quieres saber si la palabra 'YouTube' esta en self.comando_de_audio y si esa no está buscar la palabra 'youtube'. Hacerlo de la forma en la que lo hiciste no te va a funcionar. Tienes que hacer `'YouTube' in self.comando_de_audio or 'youtube' in self.comando_de_audio`. Lo mismo aplica a esta linea: `('Telegram' or 'telegram') in self.comando_de_audio`

Comment: Gracias por responder rápido, ahora me salta este error
ile "c:/Users/Jeremias Davison/Downloads/contraseñaRandom.py", line 81, in <module>
    Jueves.Run()
TypeError: Run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Interpretar'
PS C:\Users\Jeremias Davison>

Comment: Cual es el proposito del argumento Interpretar en el método Run de tu clase Asistente? Si quitases ese argumento o se lo pasases, el error no sucedería

Comment: Es que si saco el argumento en la función Run no podría ejecutar la función Interpretar.

Comment: No necesitas pasar el método de una clase como argumento. Saca el argumento y cada vez que quieras llamar a interpretar, que es el método de una clase, ponle "self." a la izquierda (self es en este caso tu asistente). Te recomiendo esta lectura para entender bien como funcionan las clases en Python: https://programacion.net/articulo/como_funcionan_las_clases_y_objetos_en_python_1505

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!